# List of Installed Features in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a place within a current SQL server 2008 installation that can I see which instance and shared features are installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't SQL Server Configuration Manager show most of the details you require?

Comment: +1 Configuration Manager will show you all of your instances and the services installed.  If you don't find Config Manager in the start menu (happens) you can add it as a snap-in to MMC.  If you have multiple versions of SQL on your box (ie- 2005, 2008, etc) use the Configuration Manager from the highest version to see them all.

Comment: Where exactly can the details be found?

Answer (score 3):

Use SQL Server features discovery report tool in SQL Server Installation Center.

Comment: Doesn't show features for me, just server instances.

Answer (score 1):

Facets under Mgt Studio should cover everything else beyond configuration manager that you are wanting to know about your SQL 2008 install (Mgt Studio...Object Explorer...Right click ServerName...Facets).

Comment: +1 here also.  Wish they had put this in 2005...